# Status 500 after adding include to database call

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor-client-side, .net-5

After I included a child object to the database call I get an 500 status on the client.
If I skip the include part it works. Except of course I don't get all the data.
Does anyone know if I am missing something or if .net 5 or EF Core 5 works differently.

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet("getsupport")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetSupport(Guid id)
    {
            var output = await css.GetSupport(id);
            //All the data is correct here.
            return Ok(output.ToList());
    }
```

Database call:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Support>> GetSupport(Guid Id)
    {
        //This gives httpstatus 500 calling from the client.
        return db.Support.Include(x => x.SupportLevel).Where(x => x.Id == Id);
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Support>> GetSupport(Guid Id)
    {
        //This works when calling from the client.
        return db.Support.Where(x => x.Id == Id);
    }
```

At the client the call looks like this.

```
var support = await http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Support>>("api/support/GetSupport");
//This returns 500.
```

Comment: 500 is a server error, which usually means an exception is being thrown.  What error are you seeing?

Comment: Nothing on the server. Like I wrote everything there is fine. The list has all the data even the included data I have a try catch in the controller which doesn't catch anything.

Comment: 500 literally means "Internal Server Error" so there is something on the server.  Try looking through your logs, event viewer, or run it yourself and watch the console.  Let us know the error that's happening.

Comment: Thank you! I was to tired to think of looking in the Event Viewer. I was missing: services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
            );